# Javascript nodes and functions use

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a table with four rows, each one with an "id", and inside each one link with a text.

I want to change the innerHTML of the clicked link with the next one link innerHTML.

So if I have this:

```
ONE
TWO
THREE
FOUR
```

and I click on TWO for example, the result must be:

```
ONE
THREE 
TWO
FOUR
```

As follows my code, which already change the order of the two first links, but it does the same if I click another link.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change()
{
var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var i = 0;
var aux = link[i].innerHTML;
link[i].innerHTML = link[i+1].innerHTML;
link[i+1].innerHTML = aux;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr id="1"><td><a href="#" onclick="change()">ONE</a></td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td><a href="#" onclick="change()">TWO</a></td></tr>
<tr id="3"><td><a href="#" onclick="change()">THREE</a></td></tr>
<tr id="4"><td><a href="#" onclick="change()">FOUR</a></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been working on this all day and I can't see what else can I do. I'm starting with both Java and Javascript, so the use of arrays and the DOM and Javascript functions is new to me.

Comment: What should happen if 'four' is clicked? Assuming the order is still `one two three four`?

Answer (score 0):

How does the code know which link was clicked? If you don't tell it, it can't deduce it magically.

First off, remove all those `id` attributes. They serve no purpose here and will only lead to confusion.

Next, pass `this` as the first argument of `change`: `onclick="change(this);"` and `function change(link) {...}`.

Now, rewrite your `change` function to find the right link to change `link` with, and do the swap as you are now.

Good luck.

Comment: Ok I will try...

I assume the id's have no purpose and I know that my teacher wants to confuse us.....

Comment: Well, IDs should **id** entify things. Something like `tablerow1` could work as an identifier, because then you know what it is. Just `1` alone could mean anything.

Comment: so if I use the event onclick="change(this)" the function know what is the row to change, I can do something like getEelementsByTagName("tr") and we have an array with 4 elements, but how does the function knows where I clicked??

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to do something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
.shifter {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<script>

function shiftRows(e) {
  var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
  var row, tbody;

  if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span' && el.className == 'shifter') {
    row = el.parentNode.parentNode;
    tbody = row.parentNode;

    if (row.rowIndex > 0) {
      tbody.insertBefore(row, tbody.rows[row.rowIndex - 1]);
    }
  } 
}

</script>

<table id="t0" onclick="shiftRows(event);">
  <tr><td><span class="shifter">0</span>
  <tr><td><span class="shifter">1</span>
  <tr><td><span class="shifter">2</span>
  <tr><td><span class="shifter">3</span>
</table>
```